# Getting an array iteration error, wondering how to fix it

Tags: python

I am currently building a web scraper for Real Estate data. I'm working in Python and I've come across an error I can't seem to be able to fix.

```
for i in range(len(s)):
                        if '$' in s[i]:
                                price.append(s[i])

                        elif 'bath' in s[i]:
                                left = s[i].partition(",")[0]
                                right = s[i].partition(",")[2]
                                bed_bath.append(left)
                                sqft_lot.append(right)

                        elif 'fort collins' in s[i].lower():
                                address0 = s[i-1]+' '+s[i]
                                address.append(address0)

                        elif s[i].lower() == 'advertisement':
                                del s[i]

                        else:
                                continue
```

Value of 's' being:

```
                display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
                display.start()
                browser = webdriver.Firefox()
                browser.get(realtor.format(format))
                p = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='jsx-343105667 property-list list-unstyle']")
                content = p.text
                s = re.split('\n',content)
```

This is basically supposed to iterate through the array s, and add them to a separate array [price,bed_bath,sqrft_lot,address] to be used in a DataFrame. I know that it is indexing properly, I've printed each line consecutively using for i in range(len(s)): print s[i], which works, but then when I try to implement logic it's just breaking.

Getting error:

```
if '$' in s[i]:
**IndexError: list index out of range**
```

Any input into why this is happening would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add an example of `s` which didn't work for you?

Comment: You seem to be removing elements with: `del s[i]`. Surely this affects the length of `s` and might mean that you run `i` off the end.

Comment: Did you mean to collect the offending indexes and remove them once this loop has finished?

Comment: Added the code declaring the 's' variable. Let me take a look but I believe @quamrana got it. What I might do instead is use a separate for loop to take care of 'advertisement' entries.

Comment: Ideally you would add a clear example of `s` as a python list, and not a code generating one, as we can't run that code.

Comment: Yeah It's okay I figured out the problem regardless; I was deleting rows within the for loop, breaking the index midway through the iterations. I didn't even need to delete the 'advertisement' values anyway, so I've removed that line and it works. Thanks for helping me see the error in my ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @quamrana mentioned, most likely the problem is that you do `del s[i]`, so `s` get's shorter and thus some indexes will no longer exist in `s`. I have 2 possible fix ideas.
Fix 1:

```py
for i in range(len(s)):
    if i >= len(s): # check if index is still in bounds
        break
    
    if '$' in s[i]:
            price.append(s[i])

    elif 'bath' in s[i]:
            left = s[i].partition(",")[0]
            right = s[i].partition(",")[2]
            bed_bath.append(left)
            sqft_lot.append(right)

    elif 'fort collins' in s[i].lower():
            address0 = s[i-1]+' '+s[i]
            address.append(address0)

    elif s[i].lower() == 'advertisement':
            del s[i]
    else:
            continue
```

Fix 2:

```py
indexes_to_remove = []

for i in range(len(s)):
    if '$' in s[i]:
            price.append(s[i])

    elif 'bath' in s[i]:
            left = s[i].partition(",")[0]
            right = s[i].partition(",")[2]
            bed_bath.append(left)
            sqft_lot.append(right)

    elif 'fort collins' in s[i].lower():
            address0 = s[i-1]+' '+s[i]
            address.append(address0)

    elif s[i].lower() == 'advertisement':
            indexes_to_remove.append(i)
    else:
            continue


for index in indexes_to_remove[::-1]: # if you iterate through it backward, you won't have that problem.
    del s[i]
```

Comment: Second answer here would be the way I would do it if it were necessary. Appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

create a new list from s and populate it with filtered and processed data

```
output_list = []
def process_data(value):
    # your code for processing data
    ...

for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] == some_condition(i):
         output_list.append(process_value(s[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're deleting inside the for loop.
The example here throws an error as well and is maybe easier to understand:

```
s = [i for i in range(5)]

for i in range(len(s)):
    print(f"{i=} with {s=}")
    del s[i]
```

Output:

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
i=0 with s=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
i=1 with s=[1, 2, 3, 4]
i=2 with s=[1, 3, 4]
i=3 with s=[1, 3]
```